# Best Live OS for Copying Entire Hard Drive

Tags: backup, partitioning, boot-partition

I was wondering what's the best live OS for copying a entire hard drive to another one, as in a bootable backup, I'm about to use gparted to copy partitions over bit by bit but I was wondering if there is any other live OS software that works as well, as I will admit, I'm a bit larry about doing these operations every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A GParted LiveCD is just Linux (not sure what distro its based on).  There is no real advantage of booting another Linux LiveCD that had GParted.  Plus Im fairly certain if there was a difference, they would use the most advantageous kernel/drivers for GParted to work.

Comment: I guess I should have phrased that better, I was wondering if there are other partition copy/backup software that backs up bit by bit all sectors, that also has a bootable live cd.

Comment: Yes, many, one famous being CloneZilla. @user88311

Comment: From what I read clonezilla doesn't do bit by bit and excludes empty sectors, I'll have to look into it again.

Comment: I could have been wrong there. Not the biggest CloneZilla expert, but you haven't specified empty sectors. Anything wrong with `dd`? @user88311

Comment: To be completely honest the reason I was going with gparted was it was easiest for me use to, but as of about 20 minutes ago I found out it actually doesn't copy the empty sectors, in all honesty if you could direct me to a how to for dd I would be grateful as I need to get the data backed up ASAP, today being ideal.